# Something is blocking Java and I do not know what

Tags: windows-7, java, kaspersky

Something is blocking java on my computer but I don't know what. I have Kaspersky installed and I suspected it caused the problem. I tested to shut down Kaspersky and something still blocks Java.

If I boot in safe mode all works well, so some program is definitely blocking java. The picture in the screen is in Swedish and says:

> Security settings have stopped the application
>
> Name: DrawTest
>
> Location: file://
>
> security settings have stopped a local application from running

I suspect that this is caused by java itself but when I try to disable java security from the Control Panel it still stops applets and other java programs.

Answer (score 1):

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376087/run-local-java-applet-in-browser-chrome-firefox-your-security-settings-have-b

It looks like Java is stopping your Java applet from running. It's all about security for Java at the moment after a few embarrassing security holes.

Three options mentioned in the above question...

- Use AppletViewer, the guy mentions Appleteer though the link has rotter.
- Lower your Java security settings to medium. Increases your vulnerability.
- Add the address (with the file://) to your exceptions list. Has to change each time the address changes.